# Notion widget by Scriptable

Tags: notion-api, scriptable

I've tried to create `Scriptable` widget using `Notion API`.
I need to get count of page inside DB.

So, I used [guide](https://developers.notion.com/docs/getting-started) to create token and share DB, and by this [guide](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query) I create cURL request:

```
  curl 'https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/%DB_ID%/query' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer %TOKEN%' \
  -H 'Notion-Version: 2021-05-13' \
  --data '{
      "filter": 

            {

            }
        }'
```

The filter in body is required, without this param you will get error.

So, the curl works fine.

---

Then I've tried to create scriptable code:

```
async function notion_fetchData() {

  const url = 'https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/%DB_ID%/query'
  request = new Request(url)
  request.headers = {'Authorization':Bearer ${todoist_Api_key}, 'Notion-Version': '2021-05-13'}
  request.body = Data.fromString('{"filter": {}}')

  const res_notion = await request.loadJSON()
  console.log(res_notion)
  return res_notion
}
```

And this code gets error: "resource exceeds maximum size".
**Any ideas how to debug this error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the Slack community, we find the answer is that on iOS13, it is not allowed to add a body in GET request. To make it work again, we can either switch to a POST/PUT request or add body value via url parameters of the GET request.

Code in official notion js client:

```
const databasesQuery = {
  //POST instead GET
  method: "post",
  pathParams: ["database_id"],
  queryParams: [],
  bodyParams: ["filter", "sorts", "start_cursor", "page_size"],
  path: (p) => `databases/${p.database_id}/query`,
```